# Comparing strings in laravel 5 blade

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have this in my blade file:

```
 <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">
   @foreach ($category as $h)
     @if ({{$h->id}} == {{$directory->category}})
      <option value="{{$h->id}}" selected>{{$h->name}}</option>
     @else
      <option value="{{$h->id}}">{{$h->name}}</option>
     @endif
   @endforeach
</select>
```

and controller:

```
    $directory= Directory::find($id);
    $category = StoreCategory::all();
    return view('edit')->with('category', $category)->with('directory', $directory);
```

Upon opening edit, I am getting "syntax error, unexpected '<'"

Tried removing the if-else condition and it is working fine.

Comment: unexpected < on which line

Comment: this line: @if ({{$h->id}} == {{$directory->category}})

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ِYou shouldn't use `{{ ... }}` in your `if` block. Change it to:

```
@if ( $h->id == $directory->category )
```